# Are any way to use read_csv without creating files? Using StringIO

Tags: python, pandas

Is any pretty way  to create DataFrame without creating file, using StringIO?

```
import pandas as pd

Data=["Header\n","one\n", "two\n", "three\n"]
with open ("chat1.tmp", "w", encoding="utf-8")  as handle:
    handle.writelines(Data)
df = pd.read_csv("chat1.tmp", delimiter='~',  error_bad_lines=False, dtype = str)
```

I want to leave handle.writelines() for debugging proposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StringIO` with `join`:

```
from io import StringIO

Data=["Header\n","one\n", "two\n", "three\n"]

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(''.join(Data)), sep='~',  error_bad_lines=False, dtype = str)

print (df)

  Header
0    one
1    two
2  three
```

If need write data from list in loop:

```
from io import StringIO

Data=["Header\n","one\n", "two\n", "three\n"]

output = StringIO()
for val in Data:
    output.write(val)
 
output.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(output, sep='~',  error_bad_lines=False, dtype = str)
print (df)
  Header
0    one
1    two
2  three
```

Comment: No any alternatives to writelines()?

Comment: @MaximSheludyakov - Answer was edited for write to `StringIO` object in loop.